# How to close TPopupMenu programamaticly

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I want to close a `TPopupMenu` when the mouse goes out of the menu. When I want to close it, I use `SendMessage(hPopupWnd, WM_IME_KEYDOWN, VK_ESCAPE, 0)`. The problem is, if there are opened submenus, it only closes the last level, the rest stay open. Is there any way to close all of the submenus at once?

Comment: `WM_CANCELMODE`? Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239444/how-to-find-and-close-popup-menu-in-delphi ?

Comment: To detect when the mouse go out of TPopupMenu, you must install a mouse hook and from that mouse hook you can check if the mouse is above a popup menu item. I don't know what you intent to do, but at first glance the behavior you try to code is - for the less - very strange. Maybe you should explain the problem you have behind your question?

Comment: Thank you @AndreasRejbrand that worked...